# sos Job scheduler

Tags: scheduling, scheduler, scheduled-tasks

i am using sos job scheduler which support many language.i accept the shell script to write jobs but i am not a shell script writer.i want to implement a following points in job scheduler:

1. execute a shell script A. script A return "success" if time is between 6:00AM and 3PM.else it return "fail".
2. on "success" execute a shell script C or on "Fail" it execute shell script B.
3. Script B and Script C send email with“Success” or “Failure” in subject line.

please help me to sortout the above discuss problem.

Thanks

Comment: Why has it to be in shell script, and no in python or perl ?

Comment: why must it be a python or a perl script ? This guy is probably onto some kind of homework. keywords like "discuss", "following points"

Comment: @Guillaume: get good at shell. This is in fact a great problem for shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two command line utilities that are helpful in this case:

- `date`: Displays the current time/date in a specified format.
- `mail`: Sends e-mail from the command line.

Since we only need the full hour for our logic I use the date format "+%H" (hour from 0-23). This gives the following script basis:

```
#!/bin/sh
hour=$(date +%H)
if [ $hour -gt 6 -a $hour -lt 15 ]; then
    echo "message body" | mail -s Success <your e-mail address>
else
    echo "message body" | mail -s Failure <your e-mail address>
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

hour=$(date +%H)
recipient="root"
case "$hour" in
  [6-9]|1[0-5]) 
    subject="success"
    body="message"
     ;;
  *)
    subject="failure"
    body="message"
     ;;
esac
echo $body | mailx -s "$subject" "$recipient"
```